# Wordpress Custom Logo not showing on all pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I've been handed the admin panel of a wordpress site someone else built http://www.humanutopia.com.

I am trying to add a new custom logo which I have done for the first page (via theme options - header), but it doesn't seem to work on the other pages, they are loading a copy of our old logo. 
New Logo: http://www.humanutopia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/website-logo.png

Old Logo: http://www.humanutopia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/hulogo-e1461777462384.png

Does anyone have an idea about why this might be? Thank you

Comment: are you using multple header files?

Comment: You could check individual page for custom logos, had this problem before where every page has a custom header section where you could set custom attributes for specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be cache issue.

Clear the the cache and check.

Are you using any cache plugin?

Just try this URL in your browser.

http://www.humanutopia.com/work-experience/?test=test

http://www.humanutopia.com/careers/?test=test

Answer (score 1):

It can be the cache issue please clear your cache . 
Try to clear you site cache

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: @Ignatius This does not have broken links. Its much better.